# if __name__ == '__main__' function call

Tags: python

I am trying to work around a problem I have encountered in a piece of code I need to build on. I have a python module that I need to be able to import and pass arguments that will then be parsed by the main module. What I have been given looks like this:

```
#main.py
if __name__ == '__main__' 
    sys.argv[] #pass arguments if given and whatnot
    Do stuff...
```

What I need is to add a `main()` function that can take argument(s) and parse them and then pass them on like so:

```
#main.py with def main()
def main(args):
    #parse args
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[] #pass arguments if given and whatnot
    main(sys.argv)
    Do stuff...
```

To sum up: I need to import main.py and pass in arguments that are parsed by the `main()` function and then give the returned information to the `if __name_ == '__main_'` part.

**EDIT**
To clarify what I am doing

```
#hello_main.py 
import main.py

print(main.main("Hello, main"))
```

**ALSO** I want to still be able to call main.py from shell via

```
$: python main.py "Hello, main"
```

Thus preserving the **name** == **main**

Is what I am asking even possible? I have been spending the better part of today researching this issue because I would like to, if at all possible, preserve the main.py module that I have been given.

Thanks,

dmg

Comment: What have you tried? What Errors are you getting? Please tell me you did not waste an entire day of your precious mortality "researching" this problem without running code.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` part is only executed when the module is _called_, not imported.

Comment: What is wrong with calling your `main` in the `if __name__ =='__main__'` with the arguments passed by sys.argv?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: How do you _call_ a module?

Comment: @martineau call is too broad, yes. I meant run from the terminal or execfile from another module.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have been running my code each time looking for a solution. I edited my question to hopefully clarify some of what I am doing.

Comment: @M.T I edited my question to clarify. I am calling main(sys.argv) in the if __name__ == '__main__': but encounter ArgumentParser error object has no args when trying to run the main.py from the shell by just passing in arguments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Within a module file you can write `if __name__ == "__main__"` to get specific behaviour when calling that file directly, e.g. via shell:

```
#mymodule.py
import sys
def func(args):
    return 2*args

#This only happens when mymodule.py is called directly:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    double_args = func(sys.argv[1])
    print("In mymodule:",double_args)
```

One can then still use the function when importing to another file:

```
#test.py
import mymodule
print("In test:",mymodule.func("test "))
```

Thus, calling `python test.py` will result in `"In test: test test "`, while calling `python mymodule.py hello` will result in `"In mymodule: hellohello"`.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you.