# First app error IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I made a simple calculator and I'm trying to make it restart but I get this error

```
> F:\newb\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/newb/python.py   File
> "F:/newb/python.py", line 4
>     what = input("Choose your operation:")
>        ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
# Calculator

def main():
what = input("Choose your operation:")

number = float( input("Whats ur number 1?") )
number2 = float( input("Whats ur number 2?") )

if what == "+":
    result = number + number2
    print("Result: " + str(result))
elif what == "-":
    result = number - number2
    print("Result: " + str(result))
elif what == "*":
    result = number * number2
    print("Result: " + str(result))
elif what == "/":
    result = number / number2
    print("Result: " + str(result))
else:
    print(" Choose a correct operation ")

restart = input("do you wish to start again?").lower()
if restart == "yes":
    main()

else:
    exit()
```

It was working before I added `def main():` and the restart code at the bottom

Comment: You need to indent everything that you want to be in your main function.

Comment: Re-read the error, don't stop til you get it.

Comment: Python uses indentation to structure its code blocks. You will need to use either four spaces or a tab (depending on your system) to indent every line within a function or loop.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, indentation is like the brackets in other languages. To mark code blocks, the entire block needs to be indented, so in Python, unlike most other languages, *whitespace is important*. Please have a read of [this resource](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) if you'd like to learn more.

I've fixed your code in the below statement, if you're looking to understand how to indent a main function:

```
def main():
# You need to everything that belongs to the main function indent here, like so!
    what = input("Choose your operation:")    
    number = float( input("Whats ur number 1?") )
    number2 = float( input("Whats ur number 2?") )

    if what == "+":
        result = number + number2
        print("Result: " + str(result))
    elif what == "-":
        result = number - number2
        print("Result: " + str(result))
    elif what == "*":
        result = number * number2
        print("Result: " + str(result))
    elif what == "/":
        result = number / number2
        print("Result: " + str(result))
    else:
        print(" Choose a correct operation ")

# notice we de-indent here, so that we end the main function.
# add in a main line to start the code once
main()
restart = input("do you wish to start again?").lower()
if restart == "yes":
    main()
else:
    exit()
```

Although I would recommend making a 'main' function in the following way instead (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012140/if-name-main-function-call):

```
def perform_calculation():
    what = input("Choose your operation:")    
    number = float( input("Whats ur number 1?") )
    number2 = float( input("Whats ur number 2?") )
    ../ # rest of your code

# notice we de-indent here, so that we end the perform_calculation() function.
# The following only runs if you run the file directly:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_calculation()
    restart = input("do you wish to start again?").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        perform_calculation
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: Edited to make a best practices addition on how to make a 'main' function in Python